# linq many to many, how to clear the "join" table?

Tags: linq, join, many-to-many

Here is my class Formation :

```
namespace CVtheque.Entities
{
    public class Formation
    {

        public Formation()
        {
            this.CVs = new HashSet<CV>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<CV> CVs { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Here is my class CV

```
namespace CVtheque.Entities
{
    public class CV
    {
        public CV()
        {
            this.Formations = new HashSet<Formation>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Formation> Formations { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("CVs")]
        public Personne Personne { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I created a DBContext from these 2 classes and the "join" table FormationsCVs was automatically created.

On a webpage the user can enable or disable some Formations per CV. How to clear the table FormationCVs with linq syntax in the controller please ? And how to insert the new couples ? (CV1Id, Formation1Id), (CV1Id, Formation2Id) and so forth..

Comment: Are you using entity framework?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete:

```
            db.FormationCVs.Attach(obj); 
            db.FormationCVs.DeleteObject(obj);
            db.SaveChanges();
```

If you want to add:

```
            db.FormationCVs.Add(obj)
            db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: hi Cata Hotea, db.FormationCVs is not allowed in Visual Studio intellisense. However , of course, db.Formations and db.CVs are allowed

Comment: Wouldn't this delete the object instead of breaking the relation? If you have many-to-many between Courses and Students, and Student stops following Course French, do you want to delete the Student, even if he still does English and Latin?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using entity framework, then it is enough to remove all elements in the collection.

A proper many-to-many in entity framework is defined two ways:

```
class Formation
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ... // other columns

    // Every Formation has zero or more CVs (many-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<CV> CVs {get; set;}
}
class CV
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ... // other columns

    // Every CV is for zero or more Formations (many-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<Formation> Formations {get; set;}
}
```

For your requirement it is important that the `virtual ICollections` are defined on both sides.

> Given a formationId and a cvId, remove the relation between the Formation and the CV with these IDs, without removing the Formation nor the CV

```
var formationToClean = dbContext.Formations.Find(formationId);
var cvToClean = dbContext.CVs.Find(cvId);
// Consider fetching these items in one query.
// However, for this you will have to join three tables
// I'm not sure whether that will be faster then this Find that can use an index

formationToUpdate.CVs.Remove(cvToUpdate);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your replies. I'll give a try , but before that i'm very close to the solution with this code :

```
// many to many add or delete


using (Context context = new Context())
                {

                    var existingCV = (from c in context.CVs
                                      where c.Id == cv.Id select c).FirstOrDefault();

                    if(formationsIds != null)
                    {
                         var clientSideFormations = context.Formations
                        .Where(t => formationsIds.Contains(t.Id));

                        var deletedFormations = existingCV.Formations.Except(clientSideFormations).ToList<Formation>();

                        var addedFormations = clientSideFormations.Except(existingCV.Formations).ToList<Formation>();

                        deletedFormations.ForEach(c => existingCV.Formations.Remove(c));

                            foreach (Formation f in addedFormations)
                    {
                        existingCV.Formations.Add(f);
                    }

                    }
```

formationsIds is a Icollection of formations ids from a form (bunch of ) . These are the formations i want my CV to have.

Its works fine when existingCV.Formation.Count() = 0, but i get a 500 error when existingCV.Formation.Count() > 0. In other words, when my CV already has some formations in the database, the code gives me a 500 error at line `var addedFormations = ...`

How to solve this issue please ?